# UITableViewCell does not animate properly if width is less than screen size

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell and I am wanting to provide some custom animations when events occur. I have been struggling to figure out why I kept receiving the same animation (I'm assuming UITableViewRowAnimationFade, the cell would just disappear and the one below it slid up) and I finally decided to dig into the problem. I found that when I set the size of the cell to be less than 320 (or I'm assuming exactly equal to the size of the screen you presently on) it will fall back to this default animation.

My custom cell is like a floating box (I have 1 cell per section, with many sections) and I set it up like so

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(5, self.frame.origin.y, 310, self.frame.size.height);
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, self.frame.size.height);
```

but I get the default animation every time. If I change it to

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(5, self.frame.origin.y, 320, self.frame.size.height);
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.frame.size.height);
```

The different animations work just fine.

Does anyone have any clue why this would be? I'm wondering if it is intended to work this way and I need to change the way my cell is setup or if there is a workaround.

Thanks.

EDIT: Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to mess with the cell's frame or the cell's contentView's frame. Why not add your own view to the cell's contentView? Then you can size your view as needed. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: I do indeed make a bunch of my own views and add them to the contentView, but as I said before, I'm kind of trying to make the cell's be floating boxes on their own. Would you like me to upload a screen shot of what they look like for further clarification.?

Comment: I was going to offer @rmaddy's solution but no reason to now. Make the contentView of the cell transparent, don't use its textlabel etc, and add your views to the contentView. This is how its done. People waste huge amounts of time trying to modify the cell itself, and Apple will override what you are doing in the end. I'm working on this exact same issue right now - subviews will animate move etc.  Work within the system and it will fall into place quickly. Also, uparrow rmaddy's comment (as I did!) - its the best advice!

Comment: @DavidH I uploaded the screenshot because I just want to make sure of ensure I'm understanding everything here. As you can see, I wanted space around the edges of the cell and that is why I modified the frame/contentView of the cell. Everything you see on the cell is added in the following way `[self.contentView addSubview:distanceIcon];` I believe I am using the contentView correctly, I really just wanted the cell to not encompass the whole screen, but I'm getting the feeling that isn't possible?

Comment: You're not listening. You make the contentView.background color clear. Then you add ANOTHER view to the contentView that has a background color - a view with a frame that insets it on the left and right. I'm doing something almost exactly the same right now! You can then add additional views to this new view, or to the content view - I'd add it to the new view and so the contentView itself just has the one view you added, and that one view contains all your other views.

Comment: @DavidH Okay, got. Feel free to post an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the contentView.background color clear, so the cell itself is totally transparent. Then you add a view to the contentView that has a background color - a view with a frame that insets it on the left and right (and possibly top and bottom). [I'm doing something almost exactly the same right now - for a new feature for my app in the store]. Lets call this view the containerView (as it will contain all the other views). You might want to set the clipsContentsToBounds property so its impossible for any of your subviews to 'stick out' of it.

You can then add additional views to the container view. Since I always recycle my cells, you want to set tag values on all the container subviews so you can easily find them and set an appropriate property (image, text, color, etc).

Comment: I just want to add onto this from my set up. If you add any borders or lines (mine was a sublayer) to your custom view, you need to override `setSelected:` and `setHighlighted:` and set handle those correctly since they weren't being faded out on click. Also the blue highlight will still cover the entire screen, and I'm assuming there is no way around that, since we aren't messing with the actual contentView?

Comment: I would disable cell highlight and fake it with a background color in  the visible content view. In my case the cell cannot be selected so I never thought about this.